# Intersection of basis of subspace is basis of intersection of subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I can't figure out why this is not true,can't find any counter example:

Given two subspaces $P$ and $Q$ of $S$ and $\alpha$ is a basis for $P$ and $\beta$ is a basis for $Q$ then intersection  $\alpha \cap \beta$ is a basis for $P \cap Q$.

Comment: If you are ok, you can accept the answer and set as solved. Thanks!

Comment: @gimusi i do not understand why this is not true, I take two vectors in basis $\alpha = (1,1,0) $ and $\beta = (0,1,0)$ then their intersection is $(0,1,0)$ and this is exactly the subspace. That's why i did not accept it

Comment: Let's consider a simple case in $\mathbb{R^3}$: 1) x-y plane with equation z=0 and basis(1,1,0),(-1,1,0). 2) y-z plane with equation x=0 and basis(0,1,1),(0,-1,1). The intersection between the two planes is the y axis which basis is (0,1,0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a simple counter example you can think to two intersecting planes in $\mathbb{R^3}$ .

You may have two basis which do not contain the basis vector of the intersection line.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what it even means to "intersect bases." If it's literally the set intersecton, then finding a counterexample should be dead easy; for instance take $P=Q=S=\mathbb{R}$ and pick the basis $\{1\}$ for $P$ and $\{2\}$ for $Q$...

Answer (score 0):

For instance, if $P=Q=S$, the intersection of tow bases of $S$ should necessarily be a basis of $S$? This  implies a vector space has a unique basis.